# Error Run configuration Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, log, log4j, log4j2

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="File"
            fileName="C:\\Users\\rosa-\\repos\\azuredevops\\AccesoDatos\\Tarea12\\tarea14\\log\\tarea14.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

**Error**

```
ERROR StatusLogger Invalid URL File://C:log/log4j.xml
 java.net.MalformedURLException: Error at index 0 in: "log"
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:709)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.fromURI(URL.java:749)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.fromUri(ConfigurationSource.java:342)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:481)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:474)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:398)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at modelo.ConexionBD.<clinit>(ConexionBD.java:14)
    at ejecutadores.Ejecutador1.main(Ejecutador1.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Error at index 0 in: "log"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forCharSequence(NumberFormatException.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:746)
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:56)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:704)
    ... 16 more
ERROR StatusLogger Invalid URL File://C:log/log4j.xml
 java.net.MalformedURLException: Error at index 0 in: "log"
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:709)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.fromURI(URL.java:749)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.fromUri(ConfigurationSource.java:342)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getInputFromString(ConfigurationFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:488)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:474)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:398)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at modelo.ConexionBD.<clinit>(ConexionBD.java:14)
    at ejecutadores.Ejecutador1.main(Ejecutador1.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Error at index 0 in: "log"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forCharSequence(NumberFormatException.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:746)
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:56)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:704)
    ... 17 more
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '4e0e2f2a' at 'null' in 'null'
```

**Run Configuration**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tarea14</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>tarea14</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

¿Cuál sería la diferencia entre confiurar el Run o no hacerlo?.

Comment: Lo pones a buscar un `C:log/log4j.xml` y nos muestras un log4j2.xml. 


¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Es verdad, no me había dado cuenta. Gracias